# My nestedif on unix shell scripting using sh has a syntax error and i can't seem to fix it

Tags: shell, unix, sh, nested-if

I'm coding a nestedif program as shown below but there is a syntax error that says "Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "fi")

```
#!bin/sh

choose=0
echo "Do you want to choose a color?"

read choose

if [ $choose == "Y" ] ; then

echo "1. Blue"

echo "2. Green"

echo -n "Select your choice [1 or 2]? "

read choice

 if [ $choice == "1" ] ; then

        echo "you chose blue"
 else [ $choice == "2" ] ; then

        echo "you chose green"
 fi

else     

 echo " invalid choice"

fi
```

I expect it to be if i choose 1 the output will be blue then if i choose 2 the output will be green else invalid choice

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: Some suggestions. (1) Recognize "y" as well as "Y", and have the prompt specify what input is expected. (2) Put double quotes around your variable references to avoid errors when the input is empty: `if [ "$choose" == "Y" ] ; then ...`. (3) Indent your code consistently.

Comment: When the user has more choices, consider `case "{choice}" in ... esac`.

Comment: "Invalid choice" is an error message, and should be written to stderr. `echo 'invalid choice' >&2`

Comment: You should also have `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!bin/sh`

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
else [ $choice == "2" ] ; then
```

with:

```
elif [ "$choice" = "2" ] ; then
```

Notes:

1. `else` is used for the final clause, one without conditions, in an `if` statement.  Use `elif` if you want to apply a test, such as, in this case, `[ "$choice" = "2" ]`.
2. Always put shell variables in double-quotes unless you explicitly want the shell to apply expansions such as word splitting and pathname expansion.
3. `==` inside `[...]` is not POSIX.  Bash accepts it but other shells, such as `dash`, don't.  For greater portability, use `=`.

Comment: Worked but it said another error which is " ./try.sh: 6: [: y: unexpected operator

Comment: Did you try using [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)?  It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @qaqu: When I copy-and-paste the script from your question and make this change, it works. Also, line 6 is `read choose`; there's no "y" on that line. You must have been using a script that differs from the one you posted.

Comment: Better yet, use `else [ "$choice" = "2" ];` . `==` is a non-standard operator

Comment: @WilliamPursell Good observation.  Answer updated to mention that `==` inside `[...]` is not supported by the POSIX standard.

Comment: Not sure about the wording `inside [...]` . It's being passed as an argument to `[` (and `]` is also passed as an argument), but maybe that's mere pedantry.  This phrasing seems to emphasize the incorrect belief that `[ ]` is some sort of operator or part of the shell grammar.